# How do I redirect errors like 404 or 500 to a custom error page in apache httpd?

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, custom-error-handling

I have created a Django project but I am using Apache as the webserver. Can anyone tell me how can I redirect an error code like 404 or 500 or 400 to a custom error html page instead of getting a standard error message on page in case an error was to occur ?

Comment: Guys, where should I create the .htaccess file ? I have tried some solutions available on the web. But none works. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just create **custom** `404.html`, `400.html` and `500.html` inside `templates` directory. Now these `custom` error pages will be rendered whenever error occurs.

Comment: The custom error page redirection works when I run the project on Django but doesn't when I run it on Apache. I initially created custom 404.html and 500.html inside templates dir. and added the urls and views and it worked for Django. However it doesn't for Apache